# Can built-in ASP.net 4.0 webform controls output HTML5?

Tags: webforms, web-controls, html4, html

We're looking to gear up and support HTML5.

I believe that the built-in web controls in asp.net 4.0 output XHTML.

From what I understand the built-in controls do not yet ouput HTML5, however is it possible from them to output HTML4?

I don't particulary want to output a mixmatch of HTML / XHTML as although I'm sure most browsers will just deal with it, it seems like an approach that will have bad surprises.

From what I understand, XHTML5 support isn't great in browsers (though I'm still researching that).

The idea being that the surrounding HTML can make use of HTML5 and the controls just use HTML4 for the moment until asp.net catches up?

Comment: You may want to look at http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/HTML_vs._XHTML and see if you can make a polyglot document for both XHTML5 and HTML5.

Comment: Thanks @Hawken I forgot about this question, I'm guessing it's not as much of a problem since updates to the asp.net stack.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj129609.aspx) output is supported:

> For HTML5 features to work properly in Web Forms or views, you need to replace `<!DOCTYPE>` and `<html>` with their HTML5 counterparts. In ASP.NET Web Forms, this code belongs in the [master page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976112). In ASP.NET MVC, this code belongs in the `_Layoutpage.cshtml` layout page.
>   Regardless of the file type, the markup is the same, as demonstrated here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

[XHTML5](http://debeterevormgever.nl/en/articles/html5-elements-ie-without-javascript) support is simple to add using a doctype, namespacing and some styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <meta name="description" content="XHTML example for styling HTML5 elements in Internet Explorer without Javascript using namespaces."/>
        <meta name="author" content="Elco Klingen"/>
        <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright (c) 2010 Elco Klingen"/>

        <title>HTML5 elements in Internet Explorer without Javascript - XHTML Example</title>

        <style>
            .section, section, html5\:section {
                display: block;
                padding: 0 75px;
                border: 5px solid #e6e6e6;
                background: #cfc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <html5:section>foo</html5:section>
        <section>bar</section>
        <!--...-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I was looking for specific advice regarding ASP.net 4.0 webforms.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj129609.aspx) magazine covers this thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's interesting I've not come across that article before.